# Is chaining multiple CompletableFuture calls, each with its own exception logic a good practice?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a flow in my project, which uploads a resource asynchronously, then performs an operation on it, and uses job polling to get the new resource with all operations performed. I've written each of this wrapped inside a completable future, making a chain of 4 future objects. Each call has its own response parsing and exception logic, which I've added to the chain as well. This creates something like

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> mysupplier1).exceptionally(exceptionlogic).thenApplyAsync(() -> mysupplier2).exceptionally(exceptionlogic).thenApplyAsync(() ->mysupplier3).exceptionally(exceptionlogic)`

I'd like to know if this way of using a CompletableFuture a good practice in general. It's not particularly hard to read but I feel this might be tough to debug.

Comment: `exceptionally` block code is different for each `supplyAsync`?

Comment: Yes it is. Each chain might throw different kind of exception depending on the api call